# If $f$ is differentiable there exists a bijection $\phi\left(x\right)=x+cf\left(x\right)$ whose inverse is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, diffeomorphism

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function
>   with bounded derivative. Prove that there exists a constant $c>0$
>   such that the function $\phi\left(x\right)=x+cf\left(x\right)$ is
>   a bijection with differentiable inverse.

I tried to do the next. Since $f$ has bounded derirvative there exists
a constant $L>0$ such that $\mid f'\left(x\right)\mid\leq L$ for
all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. And using the mean value theorem is easy ro
see that $f$ is a Lipschitz function with constant $L$. So for all
$x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ $\mid f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\mid\leq L\mid x-y\mid$.
Since $L>0$ I can take $k>0$ sucth that $kL<1$. Then I deifned
$\phi$ as $\phi\left(x\right)=x+kf\left(x\right)$. For the injective
part we suppose that there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\neq y$ with
$\phi\left(x\right)=\phi\left(y\right)$. So using that $f$ is Lipschitz
and $kL<1$ we have that:

\begin{align*}
x+kf\left(x\right)) & =y+kf\left(y\right)\\
x-y & =k\left(f\left(y\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)\\
\mid x-y\mid & =k\mid f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\mid\\
 & \leq kL\mid x-y\mid\\
 & <\mid x-y\mid
\end{align*}

That is $\mid x-y\mid<\mid x-y\mid$ wich is a contradiction and therefore
$\phi$ is injective. But I couldn't prove that $\phi$ is surjective
and its inverse is differentiable. I don't know if the $k$ that I
chose is correct. Could you help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: If $|f'(x)| < c$ then by integration $f(x)  = f(0) +\int_0^x f'(x'){\rm d}x'$ and the latter integral is less than $|cx|$ in absolute value. Use this to bound $|f(x)|$ and find the limits of $\phi$ as $x\to \pm\infty$.

Comment: But may be $\mid f\left(x\right)\mid$ could not be bounded. Isn't it? For example
if I take $f\left(x\right)=2x$ then $\mid f\left(x\right)\mid$is
not bounded.

Comment: You can also use the differentiation of the inverse for $\phi^{-1}$, substitute it in as far as possible, and then look how you have to set $c$ for the statement to be true

Comment: Yes. But all you need is that $|f(x)| < kx$ for some $k<1$ in order for $\phi$ to go to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes.Thanks Winther

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$\phi'(x)=1+kf'(x)\ge1-kL>0 $$
for all $x$. 
Hence $\phi$ stay above the line $f(0)+(1-kL)x$ for positive $x$ and below said line for negative $x$. This means that $\phi$ is not bounded from above or below, and by continuity (IVT), $\phi$ is onto.

Assume $y_n\to y$ where $y=\phi(x)$. Let $x_n=\phi^{-1}(y_n)$. Then  $|x_n-x|\le\frac1{1-kL}|y_n-y|$ and hence $x_n\to x$.
Hence 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\phi^{-1}(y_n)-\phi^{–1}(y)}{y_n-y}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-x}{\phi(x_n)-\phi(x)}=\frac1{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\phi(x_n)-\phi(x)}{x_n-x}}=\frac1{\phi'(x)}$$
(note that the denominator is $\ne0$).
We conclude that $\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable and 
$$\left(\phi^{-1}\right)'(y)=\frac1{\phi'(\phi^{–1}(y))}.$$